# Best way to restrict access Java EE RESTFul APIs

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

What is the best (and easay) way to restrict (JAX-RS Jersey) RESTFul APIs from being accessed by third party?

(I want these APIs to be used by my application only)

Comment: If they share the same HTTP session, just set and check a key/token in the session scope, which can for example be the logged-in user. This doesn't offer 100% restriction, but makes it at least harder for others to actually use your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several. In order of simplicity they are:

1. Block access in the firewall.
2. HTTP-BASIC authentication.
3. API-key (shared secret) authentication.
4. CAS
5. OAuth.

It kind of depends on what kind of additional requirements you have. But from your brief description, I would think a simple firewall is the best solution in your case.

Comment: Is firewall implemented in application level (such as Servlet Filters) or some other dedicated additional external measures?

Comment: Firewall isn't suitable if the API is used by another public application directly (e.g. a website).

Comment: @DUKE I would say dedicated external measures. But it depends on your project.

Answer (score 0):

For application level, you can try **Spring Security** http://www.springsource.org/spring-security and restrict at URL level, or if you want some more simple you can do it by using **Servlet** specification API by putting  on **web.xml**, remember restful web services life cycle works the same as servlets do.

Comment: How exactly would you use Spring Security for this? How would you machine interface?

Comment: It is implicit(HTTP-BASIC), the need for @DUKE is that he want these APIs to be used by his application only, when you add security on the application then nobody has access to the API unless you authenticate, if you are authenticated then you can have access to the full API, well it all depends on how the security is configured and the needs of the projects.